# Microsoft Cognitive Speaker Recognition API - Enrollment - Invalid Audio 400 Error

Tags: android, azure-cognitive-services, speaker

I am trying to upload audio file to Speaker Recognition from retrofit but getting the Invalid Audio Error:

please find the code below:

```
 public void  createEnrollment(String verficationId,String file) throws IOException {

    RequestBody videoBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part vFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("audio", file, videoBody);

    ApiInterface service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<List<EnrolmentResult>> call = service.postAudioAndGetResponse(API_KEY,verficationId,vFile);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<EnrolmentResult>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<EnrolmentResult>> call, Response<List<EnrolmentResult>> response) {
            Log.d("Result", response.body().toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<EnrolmentResult>> call, Throwable t) {
            //progressDoalog.dismiss();
            Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
                }
    });

}


 public interface ApiInterface {

@Multipart
@POST("identificationProfiles/{verificationProfileId}/enroll")
Call <List<EnrolmentResult>> postAudioAndGetResponse(@Header("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key") String keyValue,
                                                     @Path("verificationProfileId") String id,
                                                     @Part MultipartBody.Part file
                                                     );

 }
```

Audio is .wav format and converted to below format:

Container   WAV
Encoding    PCM
Rate    16K
Sample Format   16 bit
Channels    Mono

When i send the same from Post Man i am getting the 202 response as Success

[image]

Comment: Maybe more details about the error would be interesting

Comment: Error : 400, Bad Request

Comment: forgot to put , Bad Request : Invalid Audio Format

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using application/json for the media type? ... looks like all calls expect this , even though we are sending binary